# canal surfaces with a non-spherical pencil

Tags: surfaces, spheres

By definition a Canal Surface, $\mathcal{C}_u$, is an envelope of the one-parameter pencil of **spheres**. However, I can make surfaces with a pencil of ellipsoids instead. Are these new surfaces (with elliptical cross-sections) considered as canal surfaces as well, or there is another name/group for them?

Update:

I am working on (canal) surfaces with elliptical and even arbitrary cross-section and I want to find proper references. As cited by @Steve Kass I looked into the book: "An Introduction to differential geometry" and I realize that the term used for such surfaces is **developable surfaces**. But at the same time by definition, the directrix of the developable surfaces is a straight line not a curve.

Comment: This isn’t my area at all, but googling suggests no, these are not also called “canal surfaces” or have any similar concise name. What I see via Google and arXiv suggests sticking with “one-parameter pencil [or family] of ellipsoids.” More knowledgable differential geometers or computer graphics people might chime in. Surfaces like you describe (for arbitrary curves, not just ellipses) get mentioned here, for example: https://books.google.com/books?id=YjbWCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA300&ots=bqlBQBF5kf&dq=surface%20envelope%20one-parameter%20family%20of%20ellipsoids&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually I am looking into surfaces made by arbitrary curves, but I thought mentioning ellipses can get me to the answer. In the reference you mentioned I understand that they are called developable surfaces which is more general name.